# Embed the "following" main feed from Yammer

Tags: embed, feed, yammer

I'm trying to build a Yammer embed feed, and want to get the same feed as you get if you click the "Following" filter on the home feed

> https://www.yammer.com/contoso.com/#/home?type=following

I've tried most options on https://www.yammer.com/widget/configure but haven't been able to nail it (if at all possible).

Comment: "feedType": "user" - Should return almost the same content as the following feed. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, and might be what we ended up with since it was the best we could do, but it's not the same.

Comment: Did any one able to find solution !! i tired "feedType":"user" which is displaying All company feed ?